# How to deserialize JSON list to C# List of objects

Tags: c#, json, jsonserializer

from the AWS lambda I get this JSON string:

```
[{"Id":19162,"LotId":21243,"LotNumber":"H6469","LotType":20,"ConfirmationStatus":0,"Date":"2016-02-17T10:51:06.757"},{"Id":19163,"LotId":21244,"LotNumber":"H6469a","LotType":20,"ConfirmationStatus":0,"Date":"2016-02-17T10:51:19.933"}]
```

I have declared a class to which I want to deserialize the data received from this API.

```
public class GetWesLotToGenerateReturn
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public long LotId { get; set; }
        public string LotNumber { get; set; }
        public int LotType { get; set; }
        public int ConfirmationStatus { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm trying to do this:

```
List<GetWesLotToGenerateReturn> sample = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<GetWesLotToGenerateReturn>>(lots);
```

And I receive this error:

```
The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Service.App.Models.AdaptersModels.GetWesLotToGenerateReturn]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 268.
```

How can I properly deserialize JSON from a list to a list of objects in C#?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The sample string you've given is only 235 characters, so I suspect that's not the string you're actually deserializing.

Comment: (It's also unclear which framework you're using - is that `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer`, or `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer`? A [mcve] would really help...)

Comment: I'm using ```System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer```

Comment: @JonSkeet this JSON string is actually: 
```"\"[{\\\"Id\\\":19162,\\\"LotId\\\":21243,\\\"LotNumber\\\":\\\"H6469\\\",\\\"LotType\\\":20,\\\"ConfirmationStatus\\\":0,\\\"Date\\\":\\\"2016-02-17T10:51:06.757\\\"},{\\\"Id\\\":19163,\\\"LotId\\\":21244,\\\"LotNumber\\\":\\\"H6469a\\\",\\\"LotType\\\":20,\\\"ConfirmationStatus\\\":0,\\\"Date\\\":\\\"2016-02-17T10:51:19.933\\\"}]\""```
I just wanted to show it in more readable format

Comment: I'd be very surprised if the JSON string actually included any backslashes. I strongly suspect that's just the debugger performing escaping. If you could provide a [mcve] as I requested before, we could help you... but until then, I doubt that there's much anyone can do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your json

```
json= "\"[{\\\"Id\\\":19162,\\\"LotId\\\":21243,\\\"LotNumber\\\":\\\"H6469\\\",\\\"LotType\\\":20,\\\"ConfirmationStatus\\\":0,\\\"Date\\\":\\\"2016-02-17T10:51:06.757\\\"},{\\\"Id\\\":19163,\\\"LotId\\\":21244,\\\"LotNumber\\\":\\\"H6469a\\\",\\\"LotType\\\":20,\\\"ConfirmationStatus\\\":0,\\\"Date\\\":\\\"2016-02-17T10:51:19.933\\\"}]\"";
```

your json was serialized twice (probably by using JSON.stringify) and  needs to be fixed at first

```
json=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(json);
```

after this I deserialized it using both Serializer (MS and Newtonsoft) and everything is ok

```
var jd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GetWesLotToGenerateReturn>>(json);

var jdm = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<GetWesLotToGenerateReturn>>(json);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually didn't realised that I serialize object in lambda before sending it and in my endpoint. I've just deleted serializing in lambda and it started to work! :)

Comment: @MateoSkyline: Note that if you'd included a [mcve] from the start, this would have been easy to solve. The very first statement in the question is incorrect - because you're *not* getting the JSON you claim to be getting. Please help us to help you in future.

Comment: for beautify json you can use  https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer